# Transformation into canonical transfer function

Tags: replacement, algebraic-manipulation

I would like to transform :

This expression of the transmittance of a 1Dof mechanical system :

```
T = (k + I c ω)/(k + I c ω - m ω^2)
```

TO

[image]

with

```
ω0^2 = k/m
```

and `λ = c / (2*m*ω0)`

Can you help me to conduct these subsitutions with Mathematica ?

I failed with /. for the moment.

Thank you for your help

Comment: `T //. {ω0 -> k/m, λ -> c / (2*m*ω0)}`?

Comment: @march it doesn't work yet since ω0 is not yet defined in the initial definition of T and the same for λ

Comment: Oh, perhaps you meant `T /. {k -> m*ω0, c -> λ*(2*m*ω0)} // Simplify`?

Answer (score 1):

We can get close, but not exactly, by considering the transmittance squared and using a variable `r` for the ratio `ω/ω0`.

```
T = (k + I c ω)/(k + I c ω - m ω^2)
trns2 = T (T /. I -> -I) // Simplify
trns2 = trns2 /. k -> m ω0^2 /. 
    c -> 2 m ω0 λ /. ω -> r ω0 // Simplify
num = Numerator[trns2]
den = Collect[Denominator[trns2], λ, Simplify]
trns = Sqrt[num]/Sqrt[den] /. r -> ω/ω0
```